# Novel with random people in a cafe which time travel to the Dinosaur Era

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, dinosaurs

This novel opens with random customers and employees in a restaurant. It is the morning. The restaurant starts to shift on its foundations and when the door is opened and a huge drop off has replaced the sidewalk.

The restaurant is now in an isolated jungle area. The occupants start to look around and explore and discover dinosaurs.

I bought it in one of the discount services, and can't locate it in my Kindle.

Comment: It's not your story, but the "random people in a cafe which time travels" reminds me of Steven Brust's [*Cowboy Feng's Space Bar and Grille.*](https://www.amazon.com/Cowboy-Fengs-Space-Bar-Grille/dp/0765306646)

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly [The Dinosaur Four](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23355973-the-dinosaur-four) by Geoff Jones, apparently an independently published novel.

[image]

The Goodreads description mentions a cafe:

> They came for the coffee and wound up in the Cretaceous.
>
> A ticking sound fills the air as Tim MacGregor enters The Daily Edition Café, hoping to meet his new girlfriend for coffee. Moments later, a chunk of building is transported 67 million years back in time, along with everyone inside.
>
> Ten unlikely companions find themselves in a world of dinosaurs and prehistoric reptiles. Several survivors compete for leadership as they search for a way home, and one member of the group plots to keep them all trapped in the past...

There are apparently far more books than I'd have expected involving normal people transported suddenly to dinosaur times, but this was the only one I found that involved any kind of restaurant/cafe type place.

Comment: I was suspecting an Assiti series novel, but yours looks like it.

Comment: @LSerni Yeah, that was my first thought as well, as I've read Time Spike but of course that mostly involved a Prison, so I went searching various "similar to" lists (and the same for books that had similar premises) until I found this one.

Comment: Thank you, that is it!!!    I think I may have read the sample and put it in the wish list instead of buying it!    \